# How can I set the position for images with apache poi XWPF

Tags: apache, position, apache-poi, image

I started to work with Apache POI's  libraries this week, and I want to test them, so everything is alright but I can't achieve set the position for one picture.

Now I have this code:

```
CustomXWPFDocument document = document = new CustomXWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(plantilla));
String blid = document.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(new File("path")), document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
document.createPicture(blid, document.getNextPicNameNumber(document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG), 259, 58);
```

Where CustomXWPFDocument is an adaptation for XWPFDocument, it fix some problems with image insertions

Comment: Has there been any progress with this?

Comment: finally I used docx4java library, it allows you work over a template instead of start from scratch